# Learning Quartz and/or openGL for iPhone resources?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, quartz-graphics

I am interested in learning how to program game graphics for iPhone OS (3.x and beyond...). Can anyone recommend (based on personal experience) good books/websites that deal specifically with Quartz/OpenGL ES programming.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the most useful bookmarks I used when learning OpenGL:ES.

["18 OpenGL ES Resources That You Must Know!"](http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/18-opengl-es-resources-that-you-must-know/) - the best meta-list I could find.

[The Categorized OpenGL ES Tutorial Collection](http://maniacdev.com/2009/09/the-categorized-opengl-es-tutorial-collection/) - the best tutorial list I could find.

[OpenGL ES from the Ground Up](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) - the best step-by-step tutorial I could find.

And for reference...

[Apple openGL:ES guide for iPhone (requires login)](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[OpenGL ES 1.1 Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/)

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Reference Pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/2.0/docs/man/)

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/ <- look back to 2009 for more OpenGL posts

Comment: I've seen this blog before. Would you please give me a ballpark link so I can poke around from there? Books are actually preferred for em, by the way.

Comment: Try this: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-1-basic.html

Books are for chumps, BTW (IMHO) :)

Comment: Books are for people with unreliable internet ;)